# update help to reflect avp split to separate sound and video sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, video, help-center

https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic currently references Audio-Video Production  and avp.stackexchange.com. This should be change to Video Production, at https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Done. Added software recs to it as well.